# How to mock a method which is type casted?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

**Class to be tested**

```
public class KnockoutValidation {
       public boolean runFormValidation(String param1, boolean param1, final String param3) {
           //...
           AccessBeanFactory fact = new AccessBeanFactory();
           AccessBean bean = (AccessBean) fact.getAccessBean("abc", "xyz");
           //....
       }
   }
```

**Test Class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class KnockOutValidationTest {

    @InjectMocks
    KnockoutValidation KnockoutValidationMock;

    @Mock
    AccessBeanFactory factMock;
    AccessBean accessBean;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        accessBean = new AccessBean();
        when(factMock.getAccessBean(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(accessBean);
    }

    @Test
    public void doKnockoutValidationTest() {
        Boolean result = KnockoutValidationMock.runFormValidation("a", true, "c");
        Assert.assertEquals(result, true);
    }
}
```

**Even after mocking it is calling the actual implementation and throwing an exception** and getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException

ideally when we mock it should not execute actual method, here it is going into that **getAccessBean** method which is again a big API with a lot of try and catch blocks. So somewhere inside it is throwing an exception.

## I just want to know why mocking is not working and how to mock this type of casted methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @InjectMock won't work in this case because you are creating the AccessBeanFactory in place with a new constructor.

```
AccessBeanFactory fact= new AccessBeanFactory();;
```

You should have it as a field of the class, then the InjectMock will work, or better pass the factory as an argument.

Here is one example that should work. @InjectMock works by type, meaning that it will search through the class's field with Reflection and injects the mocks you specify with the @Mock annotation.

```
public class KnockoutValidation {

   @Autowired
   AccessBeanFactory fact;

   public boolean runFormValidation(String param1, boolean param1, final String param3) {
       //...

       AccessBean bean = (AccessBean) fact.getAccessBean("abc", "xyz");
       //....
   }
}
```

You could also try to use PowerMockito's whenNew that will actually apply to the inline class creation, but that's a dark path you should avoid and only use with 3rd party codes.

Comment: Power Mockito used with Static Method, I don't see any use of Power mockito at this place

Comment: I don't understand the downvote and your reasoning.
Are you saying that you can only most static methods with PowerMockito? Because that's not true. Powermockito will create a ProxyClass when you specify it in the PrepareForTest and that's how it overrides the creation of new classes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @JSONstatham.                                                               i have written something like this                                              
 `AccessBeanFactory fact;      AccessBean  bean;                                                                         fact=new AccessBeanFactory();                                                                 
  bean= (AccessBean)fact.getAccessBean("abc","xyz")  ;                                                           ` _ I dont think the problem is with @InjectMock _ Can you please Explain In detail.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example code and some more explanation.

Comment: **Yeah thank you so much** @JSONStatham...the answer you gave is abselutely correct.....However there are some more methods which are getting called using an object created with **new** Keyword,is there any way to mock those methods.

Comment: Yes, that's where PowerMockito's whenNew can help, but I would rather recommend refactoring those classes if possible. Powermockito uses more resources as it uses Proxy Objects instead of Reflection and can lead to less maintainable code.

Here is a working example:
http://benkiefer.com/blog/2013/04/23/powermockito-constructor-mocking/

Note that the author also recommends refactor if possible and starts with an example for that, the solution is at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way you had written implementation, it won't be possible reason is

> AccessBeanFactory fact= new AccessBeanFactory();

instead you can

`@Autowired private AccessBeanFactory fact;`

**Problem :-** Every-time you call *fact.getAccessBean* with newly created object(instead of mock) while beans are not available. So it does throw NPE as expected